# Getting error while trying to store Int, arrayof [string] pair in userDefaults

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults

```
self.fetchMin(forStartDate: start, toEndDate: end) { (min, chal) in

    guard let mins = min, let challenges = chal else {
        return
    }

    let dict: [Int : [String]]  = [mins:challenges]

    UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "WeekStates")

}
```

Hi, In the above program I'm trying to store key and array pair of string in userDefaults but if I do so it crashes unexpectedly.

If I try with one value, its working.

eg:

```
`let dict: [String]  =  challenges
 UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "WeekStates")
```

Comment: whats the crash u faced

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: its the NSException can you show  the full crash report

Comment: can I send it to your mailID? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: There will be a "Reason" mentioned in console after "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". SHare that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults
>
> The UserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or for
>   collections, a combination of instances of):  NSData ,  NSString , 
>   NSNumber ,  NSDate ,  NSArray , or  NSDictionary . If you want to
>   store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to
>   create an instance of NSData. For more details, see Preferences and
>   Settings Programming Guide.

You can do something like this.

```
let dict: [Int : [String]]  = [1:["iOS Dev"]]

    UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict as NSDictionary) as NSData, forKey: "4WeekStates")

    if let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "4WeekStates") as? Data {

        let dic = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: unarchivedObject as Data) as? NSDictionary
        print(dic!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned at last point i tried `[String]` it works.

I'm not sure whether you can store data like type of `[Int : [String]]`, As of my knowledge `UserDefaults` Property lists can only accept certain types of variables, so it has that limitation. You can store these types of variables:

1. `Array`
2. `Data`
3. `Date`
4. `Dictionary`
5. `NSNumber`
6. `String`

Comment: I am saving it has a dictionary only.

Comment: you cannot store dictionary with a NSNumber or Int as key